# Is there any way to perform client identification for desktop browsers in Ionic Framework?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have developed an ionic application which uses cordovaPreferences for getting user information on Android and ios. I am looking to use a major portion of the code for developing the web application to be run on Desktop Browsers. Is there any way to uniquely identify desktop clients in Ionic Framework? I am currently using ClientJS for the same.

Comment: I think there are couple of ways to distinguish mobile & web users, check this stack 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: I don't need to distinguish between mobile and desktop users. What I need is a way to uniquely identify all user devices that access my app.